# WPF The property 'Content' cannot be data bound to a visual element

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I have a list view and on the first column i try to bind the index of the underlying collection.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IndexConverter x:Key="IndexConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
....
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>          
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Width="70" Height="40" 
Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}, Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter}}"></Label>
                        <!-- More stuff -->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

// IndexConverter
public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
     // Get row number. This part is working.
     // Return the formatted row number
     return string.Format("#{0}", rowNumber);
}
```

When i compile this i get the following error:

The property 'Content' cannot be data bound to a visual element.

What is wrong with the binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to bind directly the list view item (which is a visual element i guess) into your content : I don't see a path for your binding, only the source.

Try to bind something to your content

```
<Label Width="70" Height="40"  Content="{Binding Path=SomeThing,RelativeSource=RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem},Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter}}">
```

Comment: What should i set to be the path? Summary of what i want: I get the selected listview item, pass that to the converter and then write the value in the content field.

Comment: by list view item you mean the item as visual component or the business object  behind (i.e one of the objects of the list which is probably bound to the list view as the ItemSource) ??